# Custom Validation Annotation for Checking if Username Already Exists

Tags: c#, validation, data-annotations

I've looked at a number of questions on creating custom data annotation classe for model validation and so far I can't extrapolate an answer from any of them as they all vary quite wildly in responses.

I am trying to run a method that returns a boolean on what's been entered into the textbox for that property but I'm not sure how to get at the property contents to run the method. Basically this is a check to see if this username already exists. Here is what I've tried but as you can see, I don't know how to get at the string entered into the field to run the method on.

```
public class Username : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {

        ADSI adsi = new ADSI();
        if (adsi.UserExists(//here's where the text entered should go))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(this.FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The value object is the text that the user has entered into the field.

```
public class Username : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        ADSI adsi = new ADSI();
        if (adsi.UserExists(value.ToString()))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(this.FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Obviously the method I use for checking if a username exists is something I wrote so you'll need to refer to documentation on how to do that.

Usage:

```
[Username(ErrorMessage = "Username already exists.")]
public string Username {get; set;}
```